# Pairs of natural numbers $(a,b)$ such that $\frac{a^{2}+b}{b^{2}-a}$, $\frac{b^{2}+a}{a^{2}-b}$ are natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$a$,$b$ are natural numbers such that both of $~\dfrac{a^{2}+b}{b^{2}-a}$, $~\dfrac{b^{2}+a}{a^{2}-b}$ are natural numbers.
Find all pairs $(a,b)$.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ each taking the values $2$ or $3$ look fairly obvious.  But what do you think?

Comment: @Henry Are those all possible pairs?

Comment: What do you think about the question? What happens if $a=b$, $a=b+1$, etc.?

Comment: Without loss of generality $a\le b$. Then use $\frac{a^2+b}{b^2-a}\ge1$ to get a lower bound for $a$....

Comment: Or an upper bound for $b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the fractions are natural (positive) numbers, we must have
\begin{align*}
b^2 - a &\le a^2 + b \\
a^2 - b &\le b^2 + a
\end{align*}
Rearranging,
\begin{align*}
(b - a)(a + b) &\le a + b \\
(a - b)(a + b) &\le a + b
\end{align*}
So
$$
\left| (a - b)(a + b) \right| \le \left| a + b \right|
$$
Since $a, b > 0$, $|a + b| > 0$, so
$$
\left| a - b \right| \le 1
$$

- If $a - b = 0$, then $a^2 - a \mid a^2 + a$, so $a - 1 \mid a + 1$, so $a = 2$ or $a = 3$.
- If $|a - b| = 1$, then  WLOG $b = a + 1$.
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{a^2+b}{b^2-a} &= \frac{a^2 + a + 1}{a^2 + a + 1} = 1 \\
  \frac{b^2+a}{a^2-b} &= \frac{a^2 + 3a + 1}{a^2 - a - 1}
  = 1 + \frac{4a + 2}{a^2 - a - 1}
  \end{align*}

  Now,
  $a^2 - a - 1  \le 4a + 2
  \implies a^2 - 5a - 3 \le 0 \implies a \le 5$.
  Of these, check that only $a = 2$ makes the fraction a natural number.

The solutions are
$$
(2,2), (3,3), (2,3), (3,2).
$$